# Why doesn't my Topshelf service start?

Tags: topshelf

I have a problem with a shelved [Topshelf](http://www.topshelf-project.com) service that doesn't start when it's supposed to: even though the shelf folder changes, and Topshelf notices this, the service is not started. No error messages (no log messages at all, actually) are shown, and I really don't know where to start looking for the problem.

This is what I have:

- I have verified in the logs that Topshelf notices a change in the folder `C:\Topshelf.Host\Services\MyService\`.
- I have verified that the file names in the Topshelf shelf folder are `MyAssembly.dll` and `MyAssembly.config`. `MyAssembly` and `MyService` are the same, matching even on case.
- I have the following in my configuration file:

  ```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="ShelfConfiguration" type="Topshelf.Shelving.ShelfConfiguration, TopShelf" />
  </configSections>

  <ShelfConfiguration Bootstrapper="MyNamespace.MyBootstrapper, MyAssembly" />

  ...
  ```
- I have the following classes in `MyAssembly.dll`:

  ```
  namespace MyNamespace
  {
      public class MyBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MyService>
      {
          public void InitializeHostedService(IServiceConfigurator<MyService> cfg)
          {
              cfg.HowToBuildService(name => new MyService());
              cfg.WhenStarted(s => s.StartService());
              cfg.WhenStopped(s => s.StopService());
          }
      }


      public class MyService
      {
          public void StartService()
          { 
              ...
          }
          public void StopService()
          { 
              ...
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Join the mailing list, http://groups.google.com/group/topshelf-discuss or post a bug https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues.

Comment: Thanks for inadvertently pointing out that I was missing the <configSections /> and <ShelfConfiguration /> tags!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out everything I included in the question was indeed correctly setup, but I had typos in other places of the config file that gave Topshelf trouble when loading my service. When I corrected those, everything worked as expected.

I'm closing the question, as the problem wasn't really here.